# Search a column but show results from another table's column in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two similar tables, both having a similar column called 'the_column'. I want to search the_column of Table1 but to show results from the_column of Table2, assuming the result to be paginatable.

FYI, The_column in both tables is a text field containing similar sentences but with different accentuations. So I want to search table1's column, which has a clean string but to show table2's column, which has lots of added signs and symbols in it.

This is where I have got so far, which is incorrect:

```
$result = Model2::wherein('the_column', function(Model1 $q) {
                   $q->where('the_column', 'like',  "%$this->searchTerm%");
                   })->paginate();
```

Comment: In Model2 defined Table2 name or Table1 name?

Comment: add the tablename along with the column name in the search criteria

Comment: The output will be shown from table2 that corresponds to model2.

Comment: Easy way => $model_1_id = Model1::where('the_column', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->pluck('the_column')->toArray();
        $result = Model2::whereIn('the_column', $model_1_id)->paginate();

Comment: are the tables related, please share how and the relating columns

Comment: No they are not.